# My jquery doc ready function doesn't recognize an external js file function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, external, document-ready

I created several functions that were working properly when I had them on the same page as the HTML content, but because there started to be so many functions I decided to move them over to a .js file. Now the initial function cannot be called.

IE8 is saying the function doesn't exist. I have confirmed the link is correct and confirmed the js file is loading. I have even linked the trigger event for the initialization to a button (with the class of loadFile) so I can manually trigger it to ensure it's not the timing of loading. I am doing something wrong here?

**Here is the link to the external script and the doc ready:**

```
//This is how we must reference external files in our configuration, 
//but this is correct, and I am certain this is not the problem.
<script src="<#=getManagedWebFileRelativePath('docAttachmentIE8.js') #>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){          
        $('.loadFile').click(function() {                   
            initializeDocAttachments(); 
        });
    }); // END DOC Ready           
</script>
```

**Here is an extract from my js file:**

```
function initializeDocAttachments() {
    //for IE8 load this form
    var docFormHTML = "<form method='POST' id='frmUploadDoc' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>\
                       <input type='file' name='data' onchange='handleFileSelect(this);' id='filesInput'>&nbsp;&nbsp; Upload a file</form>";
    document.getElementById('docAttachmentControl').innerHTML = docFormHTML;               
    docLoadDocs();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the full context of how the rest of the page is constructed it will be hard to fully diagnose.

Things I would check is to make sure you are called jquery.js before any of the code above otherwise it wont setup any of the events you're after. Have you tried using firebug and checking the console to see if it is reporting any other JavaScript errors.

You say your configuration needs you to call the external JS file in an unusual way - I assume file gets parsed in someway which then translates it to a normal link? If so, what does the HTML look like after that?

Comment: Yes, my jquery-1.7.2.min.js file loads first.  Is it possible I need to put some type of reference before my function?

Comment: Thanks for the firebug reccomendation.  I went back and in firebug I was able to find that I had a serverside script embedded in my js file.  I guess those won't load in our particular environment.   

if(<#=tw.system.currentProcessInstance.documents.length#>>0){

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in firebug on the initializeDocAttachments(); line to make sure it is reaching it? Still, you said IE is saying the function doesn't exist yet so that means its not reaching your external file to find the function.

Comment: Ah yup that will do it - gotta love Firebug :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have makes sense and works when I put the code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3PtuH/1

What is the exact error message you are getting? IS IE8 saying that the `initializeDocAttachments()` function doesn't exist?  Could it be possible that it's saying the inner `docLoadDocs()` function might not exist?

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Sat, 2 Mar 2013 07:21:09 UTC


Message: Syntax error
Line: 24
Char: 8
Code: 0
URI: https://companyName.com/teamworks/webasset/2064.0ebe35f4-c4be-4b6a-89e3-1805211d6953/W/docAttachmentIE8.js